# Iptables in ubuntu 14.04 doesn't have statistics extension

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I have an Ubuntu box and need to manage iptables rules with the help of **statistics** extension but everytime I try to run

```
iptables -m statistics --help
```

I'll get such error

> iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load match `statistics':No such file or
>   directory
>
> Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Googled loads of time and couldn't find any symptoms why I don't have this extension.

How can I fix it or is it possible to compile whole iptables on ubuntu? seems ubuntu and iptables doesn't like each other very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension you are looking for is named `statistic` (without an `s` at the end)

You may have to load the module:

```
modprobe xt_statistic
```